How to delete a chat room?
I created a chatroom and now I no longer want it. How do I delete it? I can't find a 'delete chatroom' option anywhere in the room
I see many chatrooms have been inactive for days. Would they be automatically deleted after some time? If they would, then my problem is solved.
Edit:
From the FAQ https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention

Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

So my room will be deleted after 7 days because there are only two messages.
But there's still no option to manually delete a room. Or is there?

There is no option to delete chatrooms for regular users, but ♦ moderators can (thanks @Becky for double-checking), after they've joined the room:

I guess you could ping a moderator in chat, or flag a post to request deletion, but IMHO it shouldn't be a problem to wait a week. The worst thing that can happen is that somebody else posts a message ...

Now I am waiting for the update from Glorfindel

@TangHo I have updated the answer :)

Can a  ♦ moderator from other sites like you, deletes a room under Chinese SE?

@TangHo, yes, I can. Whether I should do that is another matter; I'd prefer not to moderate chatrooms belonging to another site if it's not urgent (like one user being rude to another one).

It is not urgent, I'll just wait for the soft delete function takes effect. No one goes there anyway. Thanks for the info

You're welcome!

Even the main chat room is basically silent.  But that's okay, we came here for Q&A, after all.
